# uninstall a software programmatically in Java

Tags: java

I want to know if there is a way to uninstall a software programmatically using java.
Suppose if I have Firefox installed on my windows machine then how could I use java program to uninstall it.

Comment: Are you just targeting your program just for multiple operating system or just for windows?

Comment: @Searock: For now I am targeting just windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try invoking Firefox's uninstall program, `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\uninstall\helper.exe`, using [`ProcessBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). For example:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\uninstall\\helper.exe").start();
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, you could try and use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec( ... )` and run the `WMIC` command line tool.

For other platforms you could execute other command line programs (like `aptitude` etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You have to differenciate what you want to do:

At first ask yourself:

- How can I uninstall software programmatically, regardless on how to do this with Java. This should be a distinct question on stack overflow. And it is just platform dependant and has nothing to do with Java.

Now ask:

- How can I call external command line tools / call the windows API / do this or that from Java.